# How to use data from other policies in order to find optimal policy in model-free rl?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am struggling to understand whether experience from one policy can be used to find optimal policy.

Suppose that I have gathered many data (state, action, reward, next_state) by following random policy.

How can I take advantage of those data in order to find the optimal policy in a model-free off-policy setting?

For example in DYNA-Q algorithm after applying the Q-Learning update we save the experience by following for example e-greedy policy and then take random samples of the history in order to update the Q-values.

If I already have many many data can I use them in same way?

Can I compute state transition probabilities and rewards and apply dynamic programming to find optimal q-values in order to have better initial q-values and then apply Q-Learning?

In the following article the author states that the reason that q-learning and its variants work consistently is because they are not pure off-policy algorithms due to the fact that the behavioral policy (e-greedy) is correlated with the target policy (greedy). In my case the data gathered may be uncorrelated with the target/optimal policy so I am not sure I can use them.

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-false-promise-of-off-policy-reinforcement-learning-algorithms-c56db1b4c79a

Comment: yes, you can use data in the same way, just apply Q-learning update rule for each $(s, a, r, s')$ tuple that you have. If you know state transition probabilities then use dynamic programming, the whole point of Q-learning is to use it when you don't have the model of environment so you probably don't need it in that case, but you can still do what you suggested if you're not sure if model is correct.

Comment: Thank you Brale for your comment. I have update my question. The problem is that the data gathered (behavioral policy) may be uncorrelated with the optimal policy (target) policy and I post a reference that states that may be a problem.